# How to select elements by class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div of class `example`

In JavaScript I have:

```
var selectWithThis = 'example'
```

Using this variable how would I write a `$()` selector to select this div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var elements = $('.' + selectWithThis);
```

Note that it returns an array of all elements with the same class. If there is only one element, still an array with just an element.

Answer (score 0):

$('.' + selectWithThis);

To use what ever class/string is stored in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there's just one DIV or care for the first one only, do as Chetan pointed out, but use either an indexer or a better selector:

Get the first element (returns a DOM object):

```
var element = $('.' + selectWithThis)[0]
```

Get the first element (returns a jQuery object):

```
var element = $('.' + selectWithThis).eq(0)
```

Get the first element (returns a jQuery object):

```
var element = $('.' + selectWithThis + ':first')
```

To further get the underlying DOM object you can always append [0] to the query.